# How to find the port of a TcpServer started using TcpServer.new(0) in ruby

Tags: ruby, tcp

How can I find the port being allocated by windows to a TcpServer started using `TcpServer.new(0)` in Ruby

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using `addr`:

```
tcp_server = TCPServer.new(0)
port = tcp_server.addr[1]
```